# C# & SQL Server CE - Write to database with multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, insert, sql-server-ce, task

I am trying to write my data to the database by multiple threads.

This is what the code looks like:

This code is part of a `foreach`:

```
Task taskA = new Task(() => sim = new Simulator(home.GetRange(0, 11), away.GetRange(0, 11), this, dp, false, gameConnectionName));
taskA.Start();
```

The `dp` object is the object I use to communicate with the database. A method I wrote in the `dp` class as example:

```
public void AddSpieltag(DateTime spielTag)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO spieltags(datum) VALUES (@spt)";
    SqlCeParameter param = null;

    param = new SqlCeParameter("@spt", SqlDbType.DateTime, 18);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = spielTag;

    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

In the simulator constructor I open a new connection, every time a new task is instanced.

```
dp = new DataParser();
dp.EstablishConnection(gameConnectionName);
```

As I mentioned the method `AddSpieltag...` before I am calling it like this after the new connection is established:

```
dp.AddSpieltag(myDateTime);
```

I do not get any errors at all. The problem is that the data is not inserted into the database. I tried to instance a new simulator without using a task and it worked, but because I need to make it more than once (and faster) I would like to make it "parallel".

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE the connection string:
The gameName is dynamic.

```
private static string personalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
private static string connStr = "Data Source=" + personalFolder + @"\Ael2015\Saves\";
 string conn = connStr + gameName + ".sdf";
 sqlConnection1 = new SqlCeConnection(conn);
 cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
 cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
 sqlConnection1.Open();
```

Comment: Please, please share your connection string! Did you look for a copy of the database file in your bin/debug folder?

Comment: Be aware that SQL CE is [not thread-safe](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/641518/) and attempting to write from multiple threads is extremely dangerous. You must use a lock or synchronization around all writes.

Comment: Thank you so far! @ErikEJ the problem is that it works without calling it as thread, but making it as the code above doesnt work, so i guess it's not about the connection string.

Comment: @Dour High Arch could you please give me an example how to use lock or synchronization? Is this a keyword i need to write before the methodname?

Comment: Still not showing us your connection string, please do that!

Comment: This has nowhere near enough information for me to guess what you should be doing. Start by telling us your connection string, then start reading [Managed Threading Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. I have had a DispatcherTimer in this thread and the Tick event was not firing, thats why it didn't write to the db.